# Groupby year dropping some variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

This is the original data and I need the mean of each year of all the variables.

[image: Original data]

But when I am using `groupby('year')` command, it is dropping all variables except 'lnmcap' and 'epu'.

[image: Post Groupby output image]

Why this is happening and what needs to be done?

Comment: We can't figure out the problem if you don't provide a [mcve]. My guess is not all the data types in the table are numbers. You can check with `df.dtypes`.

Comment: Thanks, you are spot-on. It is coming as an 'object' datatype. I am new to python so how to make those to float

Answer (score 1):

Probably the other columns have object or string type of the data, instead of integer, as a result of which only `'Inmcap'` and `'epu'` has got the average column. 
 **Use `ds.dtypes` or simply `ds.info()` to check the data types of data in the columns**

 it comes out to be object/string type then use

```
ds=ds.drop('company',axis=1)
column_names=ds.columns
for i in column_names:
   ds[i]=ds[i].astype(str).astype(float)
```

This could work

Comment: Wow... you are a saviour. Big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert the numeric columns to float types. Use `df.info()` to check the various data types.

```
for col in ds.select_dtypes(['object']).columns:
    try:
        ds[col] = ds[col].astype('float')
    except:
        continue
```

After this, use `df.info()` to check again. Those columns with objects like '1.604809' will be converted to float 1.604809

Sometimes, the column may contain some "dirty" data that cannot be converted to float. In this case, you could use below code with `errors='coerce'` means non-numeric data becomes `NaN`

```
column_names = list(ds.columns)
column_names.remove('company')
column_names.remove('year')
for col in column_names:
    ds[col] = pd.to_numeric(ds[col], errors='coerce')    #this will convert to numeric, whereas non-numeric becomes NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to convert all numerical columns to float before getting their mean, for example

```
cols = list(ds.columns)

#remove irrelevant columns
cols.pop(cols.index('company'))
cols.pop(cols.index('year'))

#convert remaining relevant columns to float
for col in cols:
    ds[col] = pd.to_numeric(ds[col], errors='coerce')
    
#after that you can apply the aggregation
ds.groupby('year').mean()
```